# nav drawer and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created a NavDrawer Activity with the assistant rather with the tutorial.

Now when I want to open a new fragment it does not replace the main content but [prepends it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SnhS.png) The textfield should disappear.

I guess I am trying to replace the wrong container. But why is it the wrong one and which is the correct one

ReadActivity.java

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //more code...

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_read) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
//the probably wrong 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, new SettingFragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_read.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:id="@id/content"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_read"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_read"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_read_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_read.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.max.speedread.ReadActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_read" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_paste" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_read.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.max.speedread.ReadActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_read">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:minHeight="200dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the prefrences from XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefrences);
    }
}
```

prefrences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="foobar">

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="checkbox_prefrence"
                android:title="asdf"
                android:summary="fdsa"
                android:dialogTitle="asdf"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I hope I didn't append too much code :)

Comment: can you post the image of your final layout

Comment: sure. there you are :)

Comment: And your onCreateView from SettingFragment please and SettingsFragment layout

Comment: I just fixed an error with your XML, and `new SettingFragment` shouldn't compile, so I think you messed copying something

Comment: I cannot see R.id.content in any of your layouts. Where is it? Are you missing a FrameLayout in your layout?

Comment: yes the error came while copy/pasting it here. 
I got it from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment). What's wrong about it?

Comment: sorry for messing a bit. I was tinkering while posting...
R.id.content is actually the <include> part in activity_read.xml
As I said I guess that is the problem, but I'm not sure which container i have to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok with your code, preferences screen is just drawing on top of your old layout.

The solution for this is:
In your content_read

Swap RelativeLayout (this is not necessary, you can just add new framelayout as child to the relative layout) with FrameLayout which will be your holder for fragments

Should look something like this>

**content_read.xml**

```
  <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="JUST A RANDOM TEXT INSIDE CONTAINER WHICH WILL BE REPLACED BY SETTINGS FRAGMENT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note the FrameLayout has the id of *R.id.container*

Next Create settings_screen_layout which should look something like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note that you need a listview with the "@android:id/list" which will act as container for your preferences

In your SettingFragment Override onCreateView like this

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefrences);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_screen_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }
```

and do the transaction

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new SettingFragment)
                    .commit();
```

Comment: ok this made it better, but it seems not to remove the original content. Is this because it wasn't added as fragment?
[pic](http://imgur.com/MOtvVFA)

Comment: @MaxEisel yeah, this google example is too generic, but you get the idea